# Why number of BC should not exceed higher order of differentiation?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I am trying to understand why given a general PDE, the number of boundary conditions that we impose can not exceed the higher order of differentiation in the PDE. My intuition about this is that it leads to "overdetermined ?" systems, and that it would make the problem ill-posed (maybe only uniqueness is losed but we still have existence ?).

Thank you in advance for your answers

Comment: The opposite: over-determined systems have no solution in general. It all boils down to the same concept you find in linear algebra. If you boil that down even further, it's the same reason you cannot solve the system "$x=1$ and $x=2$."

Comment: I see thank you! So it may have a solution, but in general no. So following this logic, under-determined systems (less BC than higher order of differentiation) will lead to only existence.